# python django dynamic zipping and download

Tags: python, html, django

I have a checkbox form. I am trying to make it so if a user checks the "video" box and submits the form then the video files gets zipped and django generates a dynamic download that pops up on the user screen. I want the same to happen for the audio. BUT if the user selects both checkboxes and submits, the the audio and video files are combined in a zip and a download pops up for the user. I dont want any of this stored on the disk so I am using StringIO. No download popup comes up

html

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="audio"/> Audio<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="video"/> Video<br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>
```

python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import cgi
from zipfile import ZipFile
from StringIO import StringIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
files = 0
def zip (content):
    buffer= StringIO.StringIO()
    z= zipfile.ZipFile( buffer, "w" )
    z.writestr(content)
    z.close()
    # generate the file
    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(z), content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=z.zip'
    return response
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
mylist = form.getlist('list')
print 'Content-Type: text/plain\n'
for item in mylist:
  if item == 'video':
    files = '../download/video.html'
    zip(files)
  elif item == 'audio':
    files = '../download/audio.html'
    zip(files)
  elif item == 'audio' and 'video':
    files = '../download/audio.html'+'../download/video.html'
    zip(files)
  else:
    print 'nothing selected'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure the for loop cant work, the third code within the last elif will never be executed since it is the same as the second 
`item == 'audio' and 'video'`  is the same as `item == 'audio and True'` which is the same as `item == 'audio'`

I would change the loop code to look a bit more simple

```
files = []
for item in mylist:
  if item == 'video':
    files.append('../download/video.html')
  elif item == 'audio':
    files.append('../download/audio.html')
zip(files)
```

and then refacor the zip to handle lists of files

```
def zip (filenames):
    buffer= StringIO.StringIO()
    z= zipfile.ZipFile( buffer, "w" )
    [z.writestr(f) for f in filenames]
    z.close()
    # generate the file
    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(z), content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=z.zip'
    return response
```

You also have to make sure that the view functions returns what the zip function returns.